# Why multiple using of PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute isn't compiled?

Tags: c#, system.web

System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute defined as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple=true)]
public sealed class PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute : Attribute 
{}
```

I.e. it allows multiple usage (AllowMultiple=true).
But if I try to added several usages of this attribute to my assembly :

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyType1), "Start")]
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MyType2), "Start")]
```

I get compiler error:

> Error  2   Duplicate 'PreApplicationStartMethod' attribute

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you were looking at the [.NET 4.5 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is documented as having `AllowMultiple = True`.

The [documentation for the .NET 4.0 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) shows it as `AllowMultiple = false`:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute : Attribute
```

So if you target .NET 4.5, it should be okay.

Comment: You're right. I was looking in Reflector at C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.dll and forgot that 4.5 is "in-place upgrade". (I do have 4.5 RC installed)